# StackOverflowError because of too deep view-hierarchy in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, view-hierarchy

we get in the Play Store some crash reports of this kind:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1753)
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1726)
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:758)
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:981)
at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:425)
at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:299)
at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:273)
.
.
.
.
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11069)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2203)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10505)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:876)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2454)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

We had such an exception on one of our test devices and it came out, that it was because of the maximum depth of the view hierarchy.
I know that the recommendation for the max depth is <10.
However, this value is quite ambitious if you have a reasonably complex app.
We use AppCompat v21 and a ViewPager on the Main-Acitivity with Fragments.

For this reason i think we have alot of "meaningless" views, which simply encapsulates one child.
Or What is the purpose of the following layouts:

-NoSaveStateFrameLayout

-NativeActionModeAwareLayout

-FitWindowsFrameLayout

Overall, we arrive a total depth of 23 including the PhoneWindowDecorView.
Our Viewtree looks like this:

[Picture from Hierarchy View](http://webftp.marius-klausa.eu/views-2.PNG)

The first Views from the RootView:

[Picture from Hierarchy View](http://webftp.marius-klausa.eu/views-1.PNG)

Nevertheless, our app works even on very old and poor Android 2.3 devices.
Why does the problem still occur in the real world.

Comment: Add any such layout code?

Comment: The StackOverflow is probably Android code parses views using recursion. Anyway 23 depth is way too much for Android, you should reconsider your design.

Comment: I don't see any other solution apart from redesigning the layouts if possible or merge different items into one item and try to reduce the hierarchy and make flat layout. TIP: Use Linear Layout where ever possible instead of Relative Layout.

Comment: With respect to different layouts you mentioned these are the classes. [NoSaveStateFrameLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ics-mr0/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java) [NativeActionModeAwareLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/b6b14e4/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/NativeActionModeAwareLayout.java) [FitWindowsFrameLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ec3f49d/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/FitWindowsFrameLayout.java)

Comment: But nested LinearLayouts produces deeper hierachys than a RelativeLayout, so why i should use them when ever possible.
concerning: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html